# Raspberry Pi Noir V2 used to work before, but now gives wrong/washed out images

Tags: raspicam

The camera initially worked perfectly. But I had to twist the cable to fit my camera somewhere. After that it worked for sometime, but after a few days, it started to give wrong images. Is the cable broken, or the camera connector on the board is lose or is there something wrong with the camera.
I'm attaching the image for reference. Also, suggest a possible solution.
[image]

Comment: Replace the cable and see what happens. They are fragile and physical damage won't be obvious.

Comment: @Dougie I replaced the cable and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Replace the cable and see what happens. They are fragile and physical damage won't be obvious.